# ORM's are incapable of handling combination relationships - poopy

Tags: orm, doctrine, laravel, propel, eloquent

So I have looked at Doctrine, Propel, and Eloquent and so far non of them seem to want to consider the existence of a middle table that has a hybrid relationship between two other tables.

http://s14.postimg.org/uoo8xt1sx/Screen_Shot_2013_07_29_at_2_50_47_PM.png

`person` has a **one to many** relationship with personVehicle and this is facilitated by the primary key of `personId`.

`vehicle` has a **one to one** relationship with personVehicle and this is facilitated by the primary key of `vehicleId`.

So far all ORM's I have looked at handle singular relationships

1. One to One
2. One to Many
3. Many to Many

But not any two or or more combinations. Is that right? What is the best way to insert into these relationships (into person, vehicle and the respective id's into personVehicle) with an ORM or alternative if available?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I stumbled across it and thought I'd add my 2 cents...

While I don't know the exact domain of your objects, it's possible that vehicle and personVehicle are a good candidate for table inheritance.  This is something Doctrine offers: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

The trick here is that the vehicle model (table) holds all common fields related to vehicles but is abstract and never used.  Only the child models are used - in this case personVehicle.  Then you can easily add other child classes of vehicles too.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship you describe is a de-facto One to Many relationship between One User to Many Vehicles.

If there is a "one-to-one" relationship between "vehicle" and "personVehicle", then "personVehicle" is essentially an extension of the "vehicle" table.  If the database was fully populated, you would end up with an equal amount of rows in both of these tables, with one row for each vehicleId.  You can combine the "vehicle" and "personVehicle" tables without data or relationship ambiguity using the common vehicleId as the index.

Anyway, if you really did want to create your tables this way, you could just create three models, and have personVehicle be its own thing.  Do exactly like you say,

vehicle-(one to one)-personVehicle-(many to one)-user